# Unity Crash when I using scroll view

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
[LicensingClient] Error: Code 10 while verifying Licensing Client signature (process Id: 16216, path: "C:/Program Files/Unity Hub/UnityLicensingClient_V1/Unity.Licensing.Client.exe")
[Licensing::Module] Warning: LicensingClient has failed validation; ignoring
[LicensingClient] Handshaking with LicensingClient (version: 1.10.5+a276b43)
[Licensing::Module] Successfully connected to LicensingClient on channel: "LicenseClient-USER" (connect: 0.00s, validation: 0.01s, handshake: 0.19s)
Entitlement-based licensing initiated
[Licensing::Module] Successfully updated the access token kAL8R-_f-YRQQSaMbof-8uZ0A4oc_RhUMcGC6n3rGBk00df
[LicensingClient] Licenses updated successfully

LICENSE SYSTEM [20221027 0:13:24] Next license update check is after 2022-10-27T15:13:23


LICENSE SYSTEM [20221027 0:13:24] Current license is already valid and activated. Skipping license activation process (Provided username/password will be ignored).
Built from '2021.3/staging' branch; Version is '2021.3.11f1 (0a5ca18544bf) revision 679073'; Using compiler version '192829333'; Build Type 'Release'
OS: 'Windows 10  (10.0.19044) 64bit Core' Language: 'ko' Physical Memory: 16303 MB
[Licensing::Module] Serial number assigned to: "F4-U7JG-EAQC-DF4F-EFPR-XXXX"
BatchMode: 0, IsHumanControllingUs: 1, StartBugReporterOnCrash: 1, Is64bit: 1, IsPro: 0
[Package Manager] Server::Start -- Port 4815 was selected

COMMAND LINE ARGUMENTS:
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.11f1\Editor\Unity.exe
-projectpath
C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour
-useHub
-hubIPC
-cloudEnvironment
production
-licensingIpc
LicenseClient-USER
-hubSessionId
b19eb6b0-5540-11ed-936d-7360e4fec401
-accessToken
kAL8R-_f-YRQQSaMbof-8uZ0A4oc_RhUMcGC6n3rGBk00df
Successfully changed project path to: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour
C:/Users/USER/Documents/Develofour
[UnityMemory] Configuration Parameters - Can be set up in boot.config
    "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-granularity=16"
    "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-bucket-count=8"
    "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-block-size=33554432"
    "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-block-count=8"
    "memorysetup-main-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-thread-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-gfx-main-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-gfx-thread-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-cache-allocator-block-size=4194304"
    "memorysetup-typetree-allocator-block-size=2097152"
    "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-granularity=16"
    "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-bucket-count=8"
    "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-block-size=33554432"
    "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-block-count=8"
    "memorysetup-profiler-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-profiler-editor-allocator-block-size=1048576"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-main=16777216"
    "memorysetup-job-temp-allocator-block-size=2097152"
    "memorysetup-job-temp-allocator-block-size-background=1048576"
    "memorysetup-job-temp-allocator-reduction-small-platforms=262144"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-background-worker=32768"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-job-worker=262144"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-preload-manager=33554432"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-nav-mesh-worker=65536"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-audio-worker=65536"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-cloud-worker=32768"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-gi-baking-worker=262144"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-gfx=262144"
[Package Manager] Restoring resolved packages state from cache
[Package Manager] 
Registered 69 packages:
  Packages from [https://packages.unity.com]:
    com.unity.collab-proxy@1.17.2 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.collab-proxy@1.17.2)
    com.unity.ide.rider@3.0.15 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.rider@3.0.15)
    com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0.16 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0.16)
    com.unity.ide.vscode@1.2.5 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.vscode@1.2.5)
    com.unity.postprocessing@3.2.2 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.postprocessing@3.2.2)
    com.unity.test-framework@1.1.31 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.test-framework@1.1.31)
    com.unity.textmeshpro@3.0.6 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.textmeshpro@3.0.6)
    com.unity.timeline@1.6.4 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.timeline@1.6.4)
    com.unity.visualscripting@1.7.8 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.visualscripting@1.7.8)
    com.unity.ext.nunit@1.0.6 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ext.nunit@1.0.6)
    com.unity.mathematics@1.2.6 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.mathematics@1.2.6)
    com.unity.burst@1.7.3 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.burst@1.7.3)
    com.unity.cinemachine@2.8.6 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.cinemachine@2.8.6)
    com.unity.editorcoroutines@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.editorcoroutines@1.0.0)
    com.unity.performance.profile-analyzer@1.1.1 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.performance.profile-analyzer@1.1.1)
    com.unity.testtools.codecoverage@1.0.1 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.testtools.codecoverage@1.0.1)
    com.unity.2d.animation@7.0.7 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.2d.animation@7.0.7)
    com.unity.2d.pixel-perfect@5.0.1 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.2d.pixel-perfect@5.0.1)
    com.unity.2d.psdimporter@6.0.5 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.2d.psdimporter@6.0.5)
    com.unity.2d.spriteshape@7.0.6 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.2d.spriteshape@7.0.6)
    com.unity.2d.tilemap.extras@2.2.3 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.2d.tilemap.extras@2.2.3)
    com.unity.services.core@1.4.2 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.services.core@1.4.2)
    com.unity.searcher@4.9.1 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.searcher@4.9.1)
    com.unity.settings-manager@1.0.3 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.settings-manager@1.0.3)
    com.unity.2d.common@6.0.4 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.2d.common@6.0.4)
    com.unity.2d.path@5.0.2 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.2d.path@5.0.2)
    com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@3.0.2 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@3.0.2)
  Built-in packages:
    com.unity.feature.2d@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.feature.2d@1.0.0)
    com.unity.feature.development@1.0.1 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.feature.development@1.0.1)
    com.unity.feature.gameplay-storytelling@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.feature.gameplay-storytelling@1.0.0)
    com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@12.1.7 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@12.1.7)
    com.unity.ugui@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ugui@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.ai@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.ai@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.androidjni@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.androidjni@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.animation@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.animation@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.assetbundle@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.assetbundle@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.audio@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.audio@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.cloth@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.cloth@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.director@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.director@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.imageconversion@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.imageconversion@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.imgui@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.imgui@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.jsonserialize@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.jsonserialize@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.particlesystem@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.particlesystem@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.physics@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.physics@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.physics2d@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.physics2d@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.screencapture@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.screencapture@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.terrain@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.terrain@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.terrainphysics@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.terrainphysics@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.tilemap@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.tilemap@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.ui@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.ui@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.uielements@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.uielements@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.umbra@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.umbra@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.unityanalytics@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.unityanalytics@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.unitywebrequest@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.unitywebrequest@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.unitywebrequestassetbundle@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.unitywebrequestassetbundle@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.unitywebrequestaudio@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.unitywebrequestaudio@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.unitywebrequesttexture@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.unitywebrequesttexture@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.unitywebrequestwww@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.unitywebrequestwww@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.vehicles@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.vehicles@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.video@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.video@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.vr@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.vr@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.wind@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.wind@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.xr@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.xr@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.subsystems@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.subsystems@1.0.0)
    com.unity.modules.uielementsnative@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.modules.uielementsnative@1.0.0)
    com.unity.render-pipelines.core@12.1.7 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.render-pipelines.core@12.1.7)
    com.unity.shadergraph@12.1.7 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.shadergraph@12.1.7)
    com.unity.2d.sprite@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.2d.sprite@1.0.0)
    com.unity.2d.tilemap@1.0.0 (location: C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.2d.tilemap@1.0.0)

[Subsystems] No new subsystems found in resolved package list.
Package Manager log level set to [2]
[Package Manager] Done registering packages in 0.67s seconds
Refreshing native plugins compatible for Editor in 491.40 ms, found 4 plugins.
Preloading 0 native plugins for Editor in 0.00 ms.
Initialize engine version: 2021.3.11f1 (0a5ca18544bf)
[Subsystems] Discovering subsystems at path C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.11f1/Editor/Data/Resources/UnitySubsystems
[Subsystems] Discovering subsystems at path C:/Users/USER/Documents/Develofour/Assets
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1; jobified=0
Direct3D:
    Version:  Direct3D 11.0 [level 11.1]
    Renderer: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 (ID=0x1f51)
    Vendor:   NVIDIA
    VRAM:     5980 MB
    Driver:   30.0.15.1215
Initialize mono
Mono path[0] = 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.11f1/Editor/Data/Managed'
Mono path[1] = 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.11f1/Editor/Data/MonoBleedingEdge/lib/mono/unityjit-win32'
Mono config path = 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.11f1/Editor/Data/MonoBleedingEdge/etc'
Using monoOptions --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,embedding=1,server=y,suspend=n,address=127.0.0.1:56440
Using cacheserver namespaces - metadata:defaultmetadata, artifacts:defaultartifacts
Using cacheserver namespaces - metadata:defaultmetadata, artifacts:defaultartifacts
ImportWorker Server TCP listen port: 0
AcceleratorClientConnectionCallback - disconnected - :0
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
Registering precompiled unity dll's ...
Register platform support module: C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.11f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/UnityEditor.Android.Extensions.dll
Register platform support module: C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.11f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WindowsStandaloneSupport/UnityEditor.WindowsStandalone.Extensions.dll
Registered in 0.605700 seconds.
Native extension for WindowsStandalone target not found
Native extension for Android target not found
Refreshing native plugins compatible for Editor in 13.92 ms, found 4 plugins.
Preloading 0 native plugins for Editor in 0.00 ms.
Mono: successfully reloaded assembly
- Completed reload, in 16.631 seconds
Domain Reload Profiling:
    ReloadAssembly (16633ms)
        BeginReloadAssembly (11466ms)
            ExecutionOrderSort (0ms)
            DisableScriptedObjects (0ms)
            BackupInstance (0ms)
            ReleaseScriptingObjects (0ms)
            CreateAndSetChildDomain (7ms)
        EndReloadAssembly (3213ms)
            LoadAssemblies (11454ms)
            RebuildTransferFunctionScriptingTraits (3ms)
            SetupTypeCache (2138ms)
            ReleaseScriptCaches (0ms)
            RebuildScriptCaches (107ms)
            SetupLoadedEditorAssemblies (786ms)
                LogAssemblyErrors (0ms)
                InitializePlatformSupportModulesInManaged (185ms)
                SetLoadedEditorAssemblies (1ms)
                RefreshPlugins (14ms)
                BeforeProcessingInitializeOnLoad (5ms)
                ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes (288ms)
                ProcessInitializeOnLoadMethodAttributes (291ms)
                AfterProcessingInitializeOnLoad (0ms)
                EditorAssembliesLoaded (1ms)
            ExecutionOrderSort2 (0ms)
            AwakeInstancesAfterBackupRestoration (0ms)
Platform modules already initialized, skipping
Application.AssetDatabase Initial Refresh Start
Registering precompiled user dll's ...
Registered in 4.819865 seconds.
Android Extension - Scanning For ADB Devices 13788 ms
Starting: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.11f1\Editor\Data\bee_backend.exe --profile="Library/Bee/backend_profiler0.traceevents" --stdin-canary --dagfile="Library/Bee/1900b0aEDbg.dag" --continue-on-failure ScriptAssemblies
WorkingDir: C:/Users/USER/Documents/Develofour
ExitCode: 0 Duration: 0s321ms
*** Tundra build success (0.22 seconds), 0 items updated, 909 evaluated
AssetDatabase: script compilation time: 1.395440s
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
Symbol file LoadedFromMemory doesn't match image C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.visualscripting@1.7.8\Editor\VisualScripting.Core\Dependencies\YamlDotNet\Unity.VisualScripting.YamlDotNet.dll
Symbol file LoadedFromMemory doesn't match image C:\Users\USER\Documents\Develofour\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.visualscripting@1.7.8\Editor\VisualScripting.Core\Dependencies\DotNetZip\Unity.VisualScripting.IonicZip.dll
Native extension for WindowsStandalone target not found
Native extension for Android target not found
Refreshing native plugins compatible for Editor in 154.88 ms, found 4 plugins.
Preloading 0 native plugins for Editor in 0.00 ms.
Mono: successfully reloaded assembly
- Completed reload, in 12.161 seconds
Domain Reload Profiling:
    ReloadAssembly (12162ms)
        BeginReloadAssembly (177ms)
            ExecutionOrderSort (0ms)
            DisableScriptedObjects (6ms)
            BackupInstance (0ms)
            ReleaseScriptingObjects (0ms)
            CreateAndSetChildDomain (28ms)
        EndReloadAssembly (11814ms)
            LoadAssemblies (6751ms)
            RebuildTransferFunctionScriptingTraits (0ms)
            SetupTypeCache (966ms)
            ReleaseScriptCaches (1ms)
            RebuildScriptCaches (102ms)
            SetupLoadedEditorAssemblies (3905ms)
                LogAssemblyErrors (0ms)
                InitializePlatformSupportModulesInManaged (28ms)
                SetLoadedEditorAssemblies (0ms)
                RefreshPlugins (155ms)
                BeforeProcessingInitializeOnLoad (205ms)
                ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes (1987ms)
                ProcessInitializeOnLoadMethodAttributes (1518ms)
                AfterProcessingInitializeOnLoad (12ms)
                EditorAssembliesLoaded (0ms)
            ExecutionOrderSort2 (0ms)
            AwakeInstancesAfterBackupRestoration (18ms)
Platform modules already initialized, skipping
Registering precompiled user dll's ...
Registered in 0.016351 seconds.
Asset Pipeline Refresh: Total: 74.715 seconds - Initiated by InitialRefreshV2(ForceSynchronousImport)
    Summary:
        Imports: total=0 (actual=0, local cache=0, cache server=0)
        Asset DB Process Time: managed=0 ms, native=7602 ms
        Asset DB Callback time: managed=48 ms, native=1 ms
        Scripting: domain reloads=1, domain reload time=12576 ms, compile time=1398 ms, other=53087 ms
        Project Asset Count: scripts=7154, non-scripts=2424
        Asset File Changes: new=0, changed=0, moved=0, deleted=0
        Scan Filter Count: 1
    InvokeBeforeRefreshCallbacks: 1.587ms
    ApplyChangesToAssetFolders: 0.159ms
    Scan: 1860.858ms
    OnSourceAssetsModified: 0.001ms
    InitializeImportedAssetsSnapshot: 17.678ms
    GetAllGuidsForCategorization: 2.575ms
    CategorizeAssets: 615.164ms
    ImportOutOfDateAssets: 67117.255ms (65714.065ms without children)
        CompileScripts: 1397.598ms
        EnsureUptoDateAssetsAreRegisteredWithGuidPM: 3.071ms
        InitializingProgressBar: 0.934ms
        PostProcessAllAssetNotificationsAddChangedAssets: 0.944ms
        OnDemandSchedulerStart: 0.642ms
    ReloadSourceAssets: 1.048ms
    UnloadImportedAssets: 42.035ms
    PostProcessAllAssets: 48.632ms
    GatherAllCurrentPrimaryArtifactRevisions: 0.000ms
    UnloadStreamsBegin: 3.305ms
    LoadedImportedAssetsSnapshotReleaseGCHandles: 2.852ms
    GetLoadedSourceAssetsSnapshot: 1.565ms
    PersistCurrentRevisions: 0.610ms
    UnloadStreamsEnd: 0.111ms
    GenerateScriptTypeHashes: 2.982ms
    Untracked: 5047.700ms
Application.AssetDatabase Initial Refresh End
Launched and connected shader compiler UnityShaderCompiler.exe after 0.15 seconds
Scanning for USB devices : 3.026ms
Initializing Unity extensions:
[MODES] ModeService[none].Initialize
[MODES] ModeService[none].LoadModes
[MODES] Loading mode Default (0) for mode-current-id-Developfour
Unloading 225 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
ProgressiveSceneManager::Cancel()
Loaded scene 'Assets/01.Scenes/Garu/SheetTest.unity'
    Deserialize:            363.139 ms
    Integration:            206.468 ms
    Integration of assets:  24.520 ms
    Thread Wait Time:       0.322 ms
    Total Operation Time:   594.449 ms
Unloading 294 unused Assets / (2.4 MB). Loaded Objects now: 6559.
Memory consumption went from 184.6 MB to 182.3 MB.
Total: 8.263500 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.536000 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.513800 ms MarkObjects: 6.376500 ms  DeleteObjects: 0.836400 ms)

[LAYOUT] About to load UserSettings\Layouts\default-2021.dwlt, keepMainWindow=False
<RI> Initialized touch support.

<RI> Initialized touch support.

<RI> Initialized touch support.

<RI> Initialized touch support.

<RI> Initialized touch support.

<RI> Initialized touch support.

<RI> Initialized touch support.

<RI> Initialized touch support.

[MODES] ModeService[default].InitializeCurrentMode
[MODES] ModeService[default].RaiseModeChanged(default, default)
IsTimeToCheckForNewEditor: Update time 1666798076 current 1666797309
<RI> Initializing input.

<RI> Input initialized.

[Project] Loading completed in 107.827 seconds
    Project init time:              0.000 seconds
        Template init time:         0.000 seconds
        Package Manager init time:      0.000 seconds
        Asset Database init time:       0.000 seconds
        Global illumination init time:  0.000 seconds
        Assemblies load time:           0.000 seconds
        Unity extensions init time:     0.001 seconds
        Asset Database refresh time:    0.000 seconds
    Scene opening time:             0.000 seconds
Created GICache directory at C:/Users/USER/AppData/LocalLow/Unity/Caches/GiCache. Took: 0.054s, timestamps: [109.106 - 109.161]
gi::BakeBackendSwitch: switching bake backend from 3 to 1.
[00:00:03] Builtin Sky manager started.
Setting up 6 worker threads for Enlighten.
[00:00:03] Finished 1 Bake Ambient Probe job (0.00s execute, 0.00s integrate, 0.25s wallclock)
[Licensing::Module] Successfully updated access token: "kAL8R-_f"... (expires: 2023-10-26 15:15:12 GMT)
Scanning for USB devices : 1.865ms
Android Extension - Scanning For ADB Devices 5520 ms
Registering precompiled user dll's ...
Registered in 0.017029 seconds.
Asset Pipeline Refresh: Total: 0.164 seconds - Initiated by RefreshV2(AllowForceSynchronousImport)
TrimDiskCacheJob: Current cache size 206mb

=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a UNKNOWN while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at UnityEditor.EditorApplication:ExecuteMenuItem <0x000e0>
      at UnityEditor.ShortcutManagement.MenuItemEntryDiscoveryInfo:<.ctor>b__7_0 <0x0008a>
      at UnityEditor.ShortcutManagement.Trigger:HandleKeyEvent <0x02040>
      at UnityEditor.ShortcutManagement.ShortcutController:HandleKeyEvent <0x000f2>
      at UnityEditor.ShortcutManagement.ShortcutIntegration:EventHandler <0x00302>
      at UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallGlobalEventHandler <0x000bd>
      at System.Object:runtime_invoke_void <0x00184>
=================================================================
Received signal SIGSEGV
Obtained 36 stack frames
0x00007ff7eeb208bf (Unity) UI::CanvasRenderer::Deactivate
0x00007ff7ede98447 (Unity) GameObject::ActivateAwakeRecursivelyInternal
0x00007ff7ede98059 (Unity) GameObject::ActivateAwakeRecursively
0x00007ff7ede9ad19 (Unity) GameObject::Deactivate
0x00007ff7ee1abe55 (Unity) DestroyObjectHighLevel_Internal
0x00007ff7ee1abaa4 (Unity) DestroyObjectHighLevel
0x00007ff7ef43d19b (Unity) CreatedObjectUndo::ApplyUndo
0x00007ff7ef43d2bb (Unity) UndoManager::ApplyUndo
0x00007ff7ef446b77 (Unity) UndoManager::Undo
0x00007ff7eef474f0 (Unity) MenuController::ExecuteMenuItem
0x00007ff7eef46bd2 (Unity) MenuController::ExecuteMainMenuItem
0x00007ff7edb7e49e (Unity) EditorApplication_CUSTOM_ExecuteMenuItem
0x0000016577c242e1 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEditor.EditorApplication:ExecuteMenuItem (string)
0x0000016577c241ab (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.ShortcutManagement.MenuItemEntryDiscoveryInfo:<.ctor>b__7_0 (UnityEditor.ShortcutManagement.ShortcutArguments)
0x0000016577c1ca81 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.ShortcutManagement.Trigger:HandleKeyEvent (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEditor.ShortcutManagement.IContextManager)
0x0000016577c1a973 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.ShortcutManagement.ShortcutController:HandleKeyEvent (UnityEngine.Event)
0x0000016577c1a5b3 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.ShortcutManagement.ShortcutIntegration:EventHandler ()
0x0000016577c1a16e (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallGlobalEventHandler ()
0x0000016444f52e35 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007fff65cafe24 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:3445] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007fff65bee764 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3066] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007fff65bee8fc (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3113] mono_runtime_invoke 
0x00007ff7ee508164 (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x00007ff7ee4e7a04 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x00007ff7ee4e2615 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke<void>
0x00007ff7ee63885b (Unity) Scripting::UnityEditor::EditorApplicationProxy::Internal_CallGlobalEventHandler
0x00007ff7ef022ada (Unity) CallGlobalInputEvent
0x00007ff7ef58cbf0 (Unity) GUIView::ProcessEventMessages
0x00007ff7ef58677f (Unity) GUIView::GUIViewWndProc
0x00007fffd62de858 (USER32) CallWindowProcW
0x00007fffd62de299 (USER32) DispatchMessageW
0x00007ff7ef5616a3 (Unity) MainMessageLoop
0x00007ff7ef5660cb (Unity) WinMain
0x00007ff7f090533e (Unity) __scrt_common_main_seh
0x00007fffd77f7034 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007fffd81c26a1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart
```

Hello, I am a beginner developer who uses Unity.

I'm using a scroll view in Unity, and if I create an object in a context object and copy it, Unity crashes. It doesn't crash right away Sometimes two copies make a crash, and sometimes more than 50 copies make a crash I got it.

Here's the crash log. What should I do?

Comment: can you show us the code used for copying, in a context? scroll view alone does not cause crashes, maybe you get into a stack overflow situation when an action is immediately triggered on the copy, this is likely to crash the editor

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a Unity version issue. In Unity 2021.3.11f version, if you copy a GameObject with Control + D and return with Control + Z, it crashes. If you are using Unity 2021.3.11f this must be the problem.
The solution is simple. You can download a Unity version higher than Unity 2021.3.11f.